# Delete from Entity Framework dynamically with relationship tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have tables with foreign keys from main tables. I want that when I'm deleting an entry also want to be able to first remove all related entities from other tables.

I tried this

```
public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : EntityBase
{
    var relationManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)m_context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(entity);
    var related = relationManager.GetAllRelatedEnds();

    foreach (var relate in related)
    {
        // what to do here - ??
    }
}
```

`EntryBase` is a base DBSet entity for all tables in DB contains UId as GUID type - the relationship is by this GUID

Answer (score 1):

you can do it automatically using small configuration using FluentAPI in onModelCreating Method by add OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) example as below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Entity1)
                .WithMany(p => p.YourEntity)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)  //This is the key to solve your problem
                .HasConstraintName("FK_YourEntity_Entity1");
        }
```